# How to autoload environment variables specific to one file path?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, environment-variables, direnv

I am working on developing a solution that simplifies hands-on debugging of failed Jenkins builds. This involves SSH-ing to the right Jenkins node and going directly on the WORKSPACE so you can interactively try different changes that could solve your problem.

While I solved the problem of starting a SSH session in the right directory there is one missing bit: your shell is missing the original environment variables defined by Jenkins, and these are critical for running any commands after that. So, not the first command of the build is a `set > .envrc` which saves all into this shell file.

My example refers to the `direnv` tool which is able to auto-load `.envrc` files. Due to security concerns this tool does not auto-load these files and gives a message `direnv: error .envrc is blocked. Run`direnv allow`to approve its content.`

So my current solution is to manually run `direnv allow` after ending up in the right folder.

How can I automate this, so I would not have to type this? A prompting could be ok because it would involve only pressing one key instead of typing ~12.

Please note that I am not forced to use `direnv` itself, I am open to other solution.

Comment: would `source .envrc` work?

Answer (score 3):

As of v2.15.0, you can now use direnv's [whitelist configuration](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/man/direnv.toml.1.md) to achieve what you described:

> Specifying whitelist directives marks specific directory hierarchies
>   or specific directories as "trusted" -- direnv will evaluate any
>   matching .envrc files regardless of whether they have been
>   specifically allowed. This feature should be used with great care, as
>   anyone with the ability to write files to that directory (including
>   collaborators on VCS repositories) will be able to execute arbitrary
>   code on your computer.

For example, say that the directory hierarchy that contains the `.envrc`s you want to be evaluated without having to run `direnv allow` is located under `/home/foo/bar`.

Create the file `/home/foo/.config/direnv/config.toml` so that it contains the following:

```
[whitelist]
prefix = [ "/home/foo/bar" ]
```

Alternatively, if there are a fixed list of specific paths you want to whitelist, you can use `exact` rather than `prefix`:

```
[whitelist]
exact = [ "/home/foo/projectA", "/home/foo/projectB" ]
```

Comment: Has anyone got this to work on MacOS, I added `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"` to `.zshrc` and created `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/direnv/direnv.toml` but I still get asked to `direnv allow` on changes to `.envrc`... I'm using on direnv 2.23.2